# JS: Difference between nested vs consecutive functions

Tags: javascript

What is the difference (if any) between calling a function/method one at a time like:

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  return arr.shift();
}
```

vs doing so one inside the other one like:

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
 return arr.shift(arr.push(item));
}
```

My guess is that this would have more relevant implications on complex functions but, when learning the basics, is there any difference on performance, best practice, etc, between the two?

**Edit:** Sry, I should have clarified this is from [this exercise](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/stand-in-line/) at freeCodeCamp and you are required to *Add the number to the end of the array, then remove the first element of the array* so the system tests the function using calls like

`nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1) should return 5`

Both things passed the tests and I wonder about their differences/best practice

Comment: Depending on what parameters the function takes, they may do different things.

Comment: those 2 examples are completely different. `arr.shift()` does not take an argument, this works because coincedentally `arr.push(item)` (which doesn't actually need to return anything) is executed before `arr.shift()` .

Comment: @apokryfos: No; it returns the length.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: @SLaks it doesn't need to return anything for the code to work is what I'm saying. It's basically programming by coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nonsense to pass an arbitary value to another function even if the current version would not do anything with that value.

In the current specification of ECMAScript, the `shift` operator does not have any arguments. So anything passed to `shift` is ignored.

With the current specification both code snippets would do the exact same thing, in same order and most likely there is no performance difference.

But you definitily should pass anything to `shift`. On the one hand everyone reading your code would wonder why you pass an argument to `shift`, and first has to check if the standard changed to have a `shift` function that accepts an argument.

And if the standard for some reason would introduce a `shift` version that accepts an argument, then your code will mostlikely start to fail.